# how to fix vue-cli-service vulnerability?

Tags: vue.js, security, npm, vue-cli

I just tried creating a new project with `@vue/cli 4.3.1`, fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10, `npm 6.14.4`. When I `cd` into the project and run `npm install`, I get the following:

```
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Running `npm audit fix` produces

```
fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 1285 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated
```

Upon running `npm audit`, I get

```
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ http-proxy                                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ No patch available                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ @vue/cli-service [dev]                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ @vue/cli-service > webpack-dev-server >                      │
│               │ http-proxy-middleware > http-proxy                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1486                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Is this expected? Normal? Possible to fix? It worries me that this happens with such a clean environment where nothing malicious was installed, but then I'm also not an npm expert... What should I do here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was setting up a new Vue project and got the same issue. I was able to find a post on Github Vue/Vue-cli where they address the issue:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5489#issuecomment-629326414

That post says they are tracking the issue, but as a note:

> Note: as it's only used for the local development server, it's not an
>   actual security vulnerability on Vue CLI projects. Feel free to ignore
>   it if @vue/cli-service is the only source of this dependency in your
>   project.

So, I have gone ahead and ignored it for the time being.  I hope that when they update the NPM package, it will use an updated http-proxy, which addresses the issue.

According to the tracker itself, it says it is fixed in http-proxy version 1.18.1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was able to solve it by updating my dependencies in `package.json` by using `npm-check-updates` (`npm i -g npm-check-updates`) by running `ncu -u` in the project folder, after that it didn't report any vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest, before creating vue cli project, upgrade node and npm to the newest versions available. I've had the same problem and this solved it partially for me(from 108 vulnerabilities before, to 45 after).

Answer (score 0):

No fixes are currently available for these issues.
npm recommends considering using another package until a patch is available

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).